# Run function after mouse down for set time jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically when you hold down any of the buttons with the class of `block_delete` for more than 1 second, the `OpenLoader()` should run. I googled and looked around on here and then made this, it kind of works:

```
var functionDeleteBlockDia = function() { 
    $(".block_delete").mouseup(function (){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        });
    $(".block_delete").mousedown(function (){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            OpenLoader();
            }, 1000);
            });

}
```

The problem I'm having is that on mouseup the `OpenLoader();` dies, I tried to unbind mouseup even though there's no function attached to it, I tried to attach `event.preventDefault();` on it as you can see above, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle for this code?

Comment: sure, give me one moment and I'll create a fiddle.

Comment: hmmm, it seems to work fine in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wjX8q/6/

Comment: I double checked and nothing is clashing, brb, let me check again.

Comment: I think it would be better to use jquery's `on()` i.e. `$('.block_delete').on('click', function() { //code here });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/nhjC8/1/

```
$(".block_delete")   
.mousedown(function (){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        OpenLoader();
        }, 1000);
 });

function OpenLoader(){
     alert('test');
}​
```